# Why changing type of pointer is incorrect?

Tags: c

I've been struggeling in understanding why changing the type of pointers are invalid.
I've asked in some places that changing the type is invalid so I've tested some codes :

1st code :

```
    int *x;
    int y = 35;
    
    x = &y;
    
    printf("%c\n", *x);
```

2nd code :

```
   char *x;
    int y = 35;
    
    x = &y;
    
    printf("%c\n", *x);
```

and the code I was provided that shows me to not change the pointer type :

3rd code :

```
    void* vp = malloc(100); 

    cp = (char*)vp;          
    for (; *cp != '\0'; cp++) 
    {
        printf("%c", *cp);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    numbytes = (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])) * sizeof(int);
    memcpy(vp, numbers, numbytes); 
    ip = (int*)vp;         
    for (; *ip != -1; ip++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", *ip);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("vp = %p\n", vp);
    
}
```

My actual problem is that I was said to not change the type of pointers. While in 3rd example it was changed 2 times from void to char to int. In my 1st and 2nd example I've also changed the type but it was invalid. I don't know why.
In 3rd example it had loaded some value, and then changed the type of that pointer. In my 1st and 2nd I've also loaded the value and changed the pointer from int to float. But it was invalid.

When can I change the type and when not ? I know that int pointer can point to char but doing for example int* x = &(char)y; Using *x will always return and int value but typing (printf("%c",*x)) will return a character as if it ignored the type of pointer :>

So when can I change the type ?

Here is another 4th example where I changed the int* pointer into a float in which it already contained the int value, the result was the float was always 0.

```
int *x;
int y = 5;
x = &y;

printf("%f\n", *(float*)x);
```

I've tried to understand when can I change the type of pointer and when not. Since the malloc type didn't really much matter as well the type after the pointer like int *x = (float*)y, here the float next to y doesn't really much matter because the arithmetics are based on the "x" type. Although it might affect the result *x will show because the float has different allocation of bytes.

Aside of this, I am puzzled when "type" matters and when can I change it while it contains a value.

Comment: That escalated fast! I thought we were getting a nice [mre] then boom. Casts in C are a blessing and a curse. Casting a value is often acceptable if there's a reason. Casting a pointer is almost always dangerous unless you're 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: Should I change something here ? 
I just didn't know how to ask something precisely without examples. Sorry if it's long if it bugs alot I can try to change it.

Comment: "_Johnny was, but ain't no more, 'cuz what he thought was H2O, was H2SO4_"... Things need to be correctly labelled to be handled correctly... C allows the value of a `void *` variable to store the address of a `sometype *` variable ("pointer"). Almost any other use of _casting_ pointers to another type is likely to invoke UB...

Comment: @Mariatto If you can show a small code snippet that you are unsure about, that would be better. You've pasted a big snippet with lots of questions. Better to ask one question. Maybe the answer to that will answer your other questions.

Comment: @Fe2O3 If it's possible to make an answer. For example changing the vp pointer that has the address of a memory from malloc changes the type while having some data. For example this vp was void and had 5 char in him, changing the type vp from void to char should give a good result but changing it into int wouldn't change anything. Like I said it would be great to point my examples, and say why I can't change here while the 3rd example was changing from void to char and from char to int ;> While when I was changing it was an error.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Will do !

Comment: Addendum: function pointers and data pointers are apples and oranges. Do not mix these two...

Comment: @Mariatto You can [edit] your question. No need to make a new one.

Comment: @Mariatto The full (and correct) answer comes from reading & understanding the C language specification. Perhaps someone will provide a link. The compiler does its best to keep programmers from shooting themselves in the foot. Casting tells the compiler to do what it's told (in the code). The programmer takes responsibility...

Comment: @pmacfarlane I've edited it.

Comment: @Fe2O3 perhaps you are right because I know in C++ it will pop an error but in C it is like a wild west, but it works by why ? I'm trying to understand when can change the type and when not while the pointer already contains an value. 

The largest problem I have is when The char contains an int number but I have a pointer to this char how does it know how it alocated this number in char so how should I change the pointer ? Well there are many questions I don't understand.

Or like in this malloc I've loaded numbers so now I have to change it into int but how do I know how it stored this.

Comment: @Mariatto Maybe you should ask a new question with one bit of code and one question. There's too much going on here. Lots of us know the answers, but you're asking too many questions.

Comment: Hmmm to many questions ? Aren't they related ? 4 codes about the type of pointer do they matter. Which questions are different ? So I can improve it in another question if it's necessary. Because I am very lost in pointers and how they allocate the data. Like integers are upside down alocated and char are alocated as read ;>
So the type is interesting thing to ask here.

Comment: @Mariatto Yes, they're sort of related. But there are many complications. Find one thing that puzzles you and ask about that. If you're still confused after someone answers, ask something else. We all want to help.

Comment: I don't know if this helps answer anything, but you cannot "change the type" of a variable by using casts. You can make a pointer to a variable, and give it a different type. It will be implementation-defined what you get if you de-reference such a pointer. Probably undefined behaviour in most cases.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I am puzzled with changing the types in pointers. But I don't know how to show it differently than using the code to experiment and the code someone told me how to use pointers. So I don't really much know how to ask this question properly, sorry for any problem/confusion.

Comment: So my examples 1st and 2nd abused the casts ? Or rather what does it mean. 
I also came up with a thing that the memory like int if it receives an char it will store it like char in int, and same goes with int in char, if I type 23 it will store it as int but read it as char. I've tested it and it worked like that. So what I write in a variable will storage it correctly but the cast will tell how it reads the allocation. Like with char = 23, it will store it like int but the char makes it read as character same goes with char in int variable. Maybe it makes sense. So the type matters then ?

Comment: And as long as I know what the variable stores I can then change it's type cast I guess like the int variable stores now a char so I can now change it's cast into char.

Comment: Good answers have been posted. I have nothing more to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot...

`malloc()` (and `calloc()` and `realloc()`) will, if there's no problem, "bite off" a chunk of *heap storage* sufficiently large to store the requested **bytes**, and aligned to store the largest datatype of the language (like an 8 byte `double`). The allocation routines are asked for a quantity of bytes and return a `void *` for the program to use those bytes as it wishes.

C allows a `void` pointer (an address) to be converted to a pointer to any other datatype (loosely speaking.) So `malloc()` returns a `void *`.

The calling function (usually) stores that pointer into a pointer variable whose type serves the needs of the function. Eg: `int *ptrInt = malloc( 10 * sizeof *ptrInt );` to allocate space to store 10 integer values. This you understand. You can play in that sandbox of 10 integers as much as you please, then `free( ptrInt );`

ALL datatypes are collections of bytes. A `char` is a single byte, and a `double` is 8 bytes. Alignment and interpretation are paramount! You can, if you want, *re-interpret* an address if you want to go exploring:

```
double dbl = 3.14159;
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&dbl; // Casting to "wrong" type...
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof dbl; i++ )
    printf( "%02x ", ptr[i] );
```

This sort of thing is fraught with danger in the wrong hands (like inexperienced programmers.) By *casting* to the wrong type, the protections (warnings, errors) provided by the compiler are suppressed. The programmer has taken responsibility and will suffer any consequences (like stepping out of bounds of memory declared to be under the control of the program code.)

A good form of casting is used to avoid nasty surprises (like a `signed char` being *sign extended* when promoted to an `int` as a parameter to a function.)

```
char ch = toupper( (unsigned char)0xF7 ); // pass as 0x00F7, not 0xFFF7!
```

In general, let apples be apples and oranges be oranges. Until one gains sufficient understanding of how data is represented in the language (and memory), stick to simple things and don't use casting inappropriately.

The compiler is your friend and it *wants* you to write good code for it to chew on. Heed its warnings as you would the warnings from any other friend. When you learn to understand its criticisms and correct those in your code, you'll be the one to benefit!

Comment: If it's not a problem I do have one question. 
I think I have an idea how it might work. For example I have int x = 'd'; even though it is a char the memory will store it, according to how the char is stored in memory. So no matter what I put into the variable it will be stored correctly but the "type" next to the variable decides how it reads the info inside of this variable. If I am correct here I think I understand something.

Also the last part of the code wasn't very understandable for me (because maybe I am a begginer), but good to know :>

Comment: `'d'` == 0x64. Storing that into an `int` will use 4 bytes of storage. `char` and `int` are _compatible_ types (one being a larger version of the other.) You've got the right idea, though! The "extra" bytes of the `int` will contain 0...

Comment: Yes I thought so, it just came up with the idea, maybe let's say long int x = 3.08 I know it is float and maybe it will show error, but let's say it worked, then 8 bytes of a float will be allocated in the memory as if it's is float ignoring the type of variable. Then if we want to read what x stores then it recalls the type variable has. I'm just saying that because malloc is just a memory and because it is a void when I store in him float (8bytes) it will allocate him as if it is a float and not a void. Why I say that ? Because int,char,float are differently stored in memory upside down etc

Comment: The compiler will see `int x = 3.08;` as text in the source file. During compilation, it will interpret the string of digits (and decimal point) as a floating point number, then see that it is to be stored into an `int`. The compiler will issue a warning, emit code to store `3` into whatever (4 byte) address is called `x`, and continue on with the rest of the code. The assembler (and the binary executable) will never know there was any "floating point funny business" in the source code.

Comment: Had you written `int x = (int)3.08;`, no warning would be issued from the compiler. The source code indicates the programmer has taken responsibility for this odd quirk. This is why/how _casting_ can get you into trouble when used inappropriately...

Comment: To be honest this breakes a lot of my ideas why it works sometimes. Because how it allocates the data. Because I thought that any number or something is stored based on what was typed like 3.08 is a float so it is stored in the memory as float but the type of that variable is int or long int (it has 8 bytes so it should work), determines what will be the output. In other words integers like 300 is stored upside down starting with data and ends with 0000000, in string the data is stored as how you read which means the first byte from "Ok" will be O, second is K etc. in float its again different

Comment: Just re-read your early comment. You wrote `long int` where I saw only `int`... You can use `long long int` to declare a variable of 8 bytes, but it will not be _proper_ to store a floating point value into it. The compiler won't emit code to do that.

Comment: I am a bit lost sorry. It might be cause of that malloc stores some info anything and changing its cast type will change how the bytes should be store ? Like it was stored as 4 bytes of chars, and changing the type will change the location of all 4 bytes to make it into int ? Weird which doesn't makes sense.

Comment: Weird even though it is an 8 byte, but it worked with char putted into int type ... I'm now more confused than before, which doesn't change the thing I have to keep it simple with assigning int with int etc. But I see many people changes the type but how it affect the already stored data in it.

Comment: Re: "upside down"... Yes. integer datatypes `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` store values in a way appropriate to the architecture of the system. (see "big-endian vs little-endian"). `signed` vs `unsigned` only alters the code the compiler emits. Floating point values are represented and stored/processed (usually) according to an IEEE standard (a convention agreed by many corporations.) When you talk about "OK", you start to talk about **arrays** of, in this case, the `char` datatype.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps yes, But still I could put char into int, although they are differently stored. But float that is 8 byte info and long int that is also 8 byte doesn't work (of course the output will be very random but it should pass because it stored 8 byte info in the memory), I don't know if it makes sense. My main problem was that the malloc or anything that stores let's say int = 300 it is stored as integer in the memory, but now it is changed into char, so it changed how it was alocated as integer into 2 chars ? I don't know how to ask this question because I am lost at the moment.

Comment: I thought that it stores something no matter what some bytes. And the type casts says how much of these bytes he read and how he decodes it. So random values I put in variables or in memory itself is stored not by the type cast but by what it is itself. And if it's not true then I am lost how it works and why I can change sometimes the type when I know every type is differently stored, like many chars are now read as one int but both of them are differently stored. float and long int are byte compatible both are 8 bytes but doesn't work  hmmmmm

Comment: Please re-read and understand my recent comment. Ref: `long long x = 3.08;` This **text** appears in the source code only. It is text. During compilation, the compiler will parse the **text** and see the representation of a floating point value. **Internally** the compiler will convert the text to a floating point value, **BUT**, when the compiler notices the value is to be stored into an **integer** datatype, apart from the warning, it will emit code that ONLY appropriate to **integer** data. The `float` aspect will not get past the compilation phase.

Comment: "_float and long int are byte compatible both are 8 bytes_" No. The two datatypes store values in completely different ways. They are the same size, but they are not processed by hardware in the same way. They are definitely "apples and oranges"...

Comment: Hmmm maybe I have an idea. Then Void type can store anything. If I put an float into a void it will allocate it as a float number. So changing the type from void to long int will give an error because even though they are byte compatible it is an error to the type cast. And if I change it into a char (or rather array of chars) it will not change how the bytes were alocated but will work. With pointers it works the same I guess ? What is also important for me is that changing the type cast will not change how the bytes were allocated at the beggining I guess.

Comment: You are right they store things in different way. So only int and char are the only compatible typecasts ?  I thought char and int have different way of storying.

Comment: `void` is not a datatype. `void *` is a datatype. It is the type of a variable that can store an address. However, you cannot access the data that a `void *` is pointing to. The language doesn't allow that.

Comment: Re: `char` vs `int`... The two types are compatible, but different sizes. `unsigned char` can store an integer value between 0 and 255. No more. A 4 byte `unsigned int` can store a value between 0 and ~4 billion... I'm sorry, but I'm about done here. You need to open a book and do some reading...

Comment: Yup but how then the value know how to store it in void. Let's say decimal number 10. Well what I understood from your info about long long x=3.08 it changes the value 3.08 into a float data which is an 8 byte info but it won't store yes ? "Internally the compiler will convert the text to a floating point value" that's how I atleast interpreted it. But also I undestand that if I said int x = 300; it will be stored as int, but changing the typecast won't change the way 300 was stored at the beggining I guess. Also as I said before why is char and int compatible when they store value differently

Comment: I read books, but as I said they are unclear for me mostly. That's why I asked here sorry ;< I want a confirmation from the above one and I can say we are okey ;>

Comment: `char` and `int` are compatible because the bits of both datatypes represent values through increasing powers of 2. They are not compatible with `float` or `double` because the latter two use a different method of "encoding" values to store those values. Go read. I'm done.

Comment: I mean the storaging in "Yup but how ....", I understand your frustration, and sorry. just tried to understand if it translates the value 3.08 into float (8 byte data) and checks where it is stored ? If yes then I am ok

Comment: please ;> Does 3.08 is from text translated into 8 byte binnary representation (floating-point-value) and then checks where it is stored and if it's int then it is an error and long int also an error even though it has 8 bytes. The most imporant question is if the number is changed into bytes (with bit values) and then compared, that's how I interpreted this "Internally the compiler will convert the text to a floating point value". Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing objects via  other type pointer invokes undefined behaviour as it violates strict alising rules, except:

1. When you access an object via a pointer to the same or compatible type
2. When you access an object using pointer to `char`
3. When you assign a pointer with a void pointer and

- void pointer is referencing an object having compatible type
- void pointer is holding reference to the object allocated by `malloc` family function.

---

- snippet 1 is correct
- snippet 2 is correct
- snippet 3 is unclear as you did not show the definition of  `numbers`. If it is an `int` array, then it is correct
- last code is invalid as you access `int` object using pointer to `float`

Comment: Re "*snippet 2 is correct*", Well, it's not undefined behaviour (because of the second exception), but it's a stretch to call correct. The intent appears to be to print `y` like in the first snippet. If so, it's not correct. It will work in some environments but not others.

Comment: @ikegami no it correct as you can access object of any type using char pointer

Comment: No, it's merely legal. Legal doesn't mean correct. It's only correct if it's also what the OP wanted to do. It is NOT a correct way to print `y`, because it does not always print `y`. If that's what the OP wanted to do (which is possible based on snippet 1), then it's not correct.